# Cannot Configure Git Repo (Azure Synapse to DevOps)

Tags: git, azure, azure-synapse

I am struggling to configure Azure resource (Synapse) to use Azure DevOps as a Git repo.

Synapse has a section which allows Git repository to be configured and I was able to configure GitHub repo, but when I want to configure DevOps one, the wizard gets stuck at loading branches from the repo:

[image]

In this case, the wizard cannot load "Collaboration Branch".

All the resources (Synapse and DevOps) are created under my personal account.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use `Select repository` to specify `Azure DevOps account`, `ProjectName` and `RepositoryName` to see whether it can load the branches.
2. Delete browser caches, and open a new incognito/InPrivate window to try again.
3. To use a personal Microsoft account for Git integration, you can link your personal Azure Repo to your organization's Active Directory:

   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/cicd/source-control#use-your-personal-microsoft-account